# Unable to connect with MTP after upgrade to 18.4.1

Tags: mtp

I upgraded my laptop yesterday to 18.4.1 and I am now unable to connect my Sony a6300 camera via USB/MTP.  The camera tries to connect but immediately goes into battery charge mode instead of allowing me to do file transfers.  Battery on the camera is fully charged and the camera connects successfully on my desktop P.C. (which is running 14.4) but will not connect to the 18.4.1 laptop.

uname results:
4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64.

dpkg -l | grep mtp results: 
ii libmtp-common 1.1.13-1 all
ii libmtp-runtime 1.1.13-1 amd64
ii libmtp9:amd64 1.1.13-1 amd64
ii libnet-smtp-ssl-perl 1.04-1 all
ii mtp-tools 1.1.13-1 amd64

Comment: Don't know if that is an option on the Sony ILCE-6300 camera, which is what I am trying to connect.  But thanks for the thought.

Comment: I don't know what "tl;dr" means.  The camera does use a card, but my card reader is unable to read it on either machine.  I have to use USB/MTP.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report

Comment: I remember having a problem getting MTP to work on14.04 LTS when I first got my Nexus5 phone.  I had to enter some commands, I think, while the Nexus5 was connected, for the PC to see it.  Then it was able connect and after that it always worked.  I don't think this is a bug.  I think I'm missing a step or two. 
Maybe I can through the steps with my Nexus5 phone and then the Sony a6300 might work after that.  But I don't think this is actually a bug.  I think there are a couple of things that I need to do.  If I figure it out, I will post it here for others to benefit from what I learn.

Comment: I successfully connected my Nexus5 cell phone to 18.04.1 this morning.  At first, all it could do was photo transfer, but after copying some photo files, I changed the setting on the Nexus5 to "file transfer" instead of "photo transfer" and the laptop (18.04.1) was able to see the files on the Nexus5.
So I tried to connect the Sony a6300 camera but it still cannot connect.
Now I need to learn how to file a bug report.  Thanks for everyone's help.